# Two radio buttons are selecting at once

Tags: html, jsp, struts

i am adding one more radio button in a `div` of jsp page. But the newly added radio button is selecting always and when i click on second radio button, it is also going to select. is there any script to write to this.

```
<div style="padding-left:15px">
        <div>
             Entry Mode Code was:
        </div>
        <div style="padding-left:30px">
            <div>
                <html:radio name="caseForm" property="questionnaire.RP0062.posEntryModeCd" value="A" styleId="posEntryModeCda"> 05 - Chip Card read (data is reliable)</html:radio>  
            </div>          
            <div>
                <html:radio name="caseForm" property="questionnaire.RP2462.posEntryModeCd" value="B"> 90 - Magnetic Stripe Terminal and the full unaltered contents of the selected track is included</html:radio>
            </div>
            <div>
                <html:radio name="caseForm" property="questionnaire.RP2462.posEntryModeCd" value="C" > Not Applicable</html:radio>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

the image attached:
[image]

Comment: Please show your actual HTML output, not your Java source code.

Comment: I believe @Diodeus meant the **generated** HTML output :) Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have the same value for the `property` attribute of all the three radio buttons, i.e. `property="questionnaire.RP2462.posEntryModeCd"` for all the three:

```
<div>
    <html:radio name="caseForm" property="questionnaire.RP2462.posEntryModeCd" value="A" styleId="posEntryModeCda"> 05 - Chip Card read (data is reliable)</html:radio>  
</div>          
<div>
    <html:radio name="caseForm" property="questionnaire.RP2462.posEntryModeCd" value="B"> 90 - Magnetic Stripe Terminal and the full unaltered contents of the selected track is included</html:radio>
</div>
<div>
    <html:radio name="caseForm" property="questionnaire.RP2462.posEntryModeCd" value="C" > Not Applicable</html:radio>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i have entered wrong name instead of given below..

`<html:radio name="caseForm" property="questionnaire.RP0062.posEntryModeCd" value="A" styleId="posEntryModeCda"> 05 - Chip Card read (data is reliable)</html:radio>               </div>`

in the above i should give `questionnaire.RP2462.posEntryModeCd` as below radio buttons also having. Then only it is working.

Thanks..